# How to set/change a cookie via php?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I use this code to change the cookie value in php, or set it if it does not exist yet:

```
setcookie('maintenance_site_contact_failed', '1', time()+3600, '/', 'entwicklung');
```

And I am using this code to set a cookie in javascript:

```
setCookie('maintenance_site_contact_failed', '0', 1);

function setCookie(name,value,days)
{
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

But as you can see in the following screenshot the cookie is created a second time instead of changing the existing one, but the duplicate has a dot in the domain name.

[image: cookies]

Why is there a dot and why is the cookie created twice?

---

**What I try:** 
If a user sends my form and the validation fails on serverside, then
I am setting the cookie `maintenance_site_contact_failed` in the  PHP script to `1` so that the client knows that an error happened.

The javascript then checks the value of the cookie, and if the cookie value is `1` then it shows an error and resets the cookie value to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your cookie is only available to different subdomains because in the php equivalent you're assigning a value for the **domain** parameter.
Try to do the same inside the Javascript setCookie function:

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "") + expires + "; path=/; domain=entwicklung";
```